# trying to schedule a task in /etc/ directory Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, permissions

I am trying to schedule a task in /etc/ directory (requires root permission to execute it as a normal user) that open firefox every 2 minutes, in a range of hours using "crontab" and append the occurrence to a file, but for some reason I can't get the firefox to open even though I did it in home/user/file/... but not in /etc/....

the time is recording correctly every two minutes but firefox is not opening up!! I gave the file Lab4 the permission (chmod +x) and my_lab (chmod 777) and that's how I got the file Lab4 to start recording the time.

here is the task :

*/2 4-6 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox --new-window http://www.google.com | date >> /etc/my_lab/Lab4

here is a pic from my VM 
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use FF? ... FF has a very large memory footprint and sometimes may take a while to start.  Your use case is unclear... However, if you need to automatically read a webpage every few minutes, you might have better luck with `lynx -dump URL` for easy formatted text output or for an even smaller footprint `curl URL` for HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like this command:

```
firefox --new-window http://www.google.com | date >> /etc/my_lab/Lab4
```

Pipes the "result" of running firefox to `date`, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Does it work better like this?

```
firefox --new-window http://www.google.com && date >> /etc/my_lab/Lab4
```

Also, another thing to always keep in mind when troubleshooting cron: try the command on the prompt first. Everything after the asterisks is just a command: does it work as expected when you run it yourself? If not, it has nothing to do with cron.

Comment: You right!!! I just realized that! I fixed it, but still can't open the browser.

Comment: If you're running Firefox from `cron`, please remember that the `cron` user/daemon will have a different PATH than you do. So, while `firefox` may start the browser from your user shell, you'll need to specify the full path to run it from a `crontab`.

Comment: Thank you so much I wish I saw this answer before spending 4 consecutive days and nights lol .....I already solved the issue and I used the same solution you're offering lol....But I really appreciate that thought :)

Comment: @FouziMedfouni if this resolved your issue, please mark it as the answer ;-)